# R creating a new column for a dataframe based on existing column using R

Tags: r

i am working with R and here is my dataframe

```
Died.At <- c(22,40,72,41)
Writer.At <- c(16, 18, 36, 36)
First.Name <- c("John", "John", "Walt", "Walt")
Second.Name <- c("Doe", "Poe", "Whitman", "Austen")
Sex <- c("MALE", "MALE", "MALE", "MALE")

writers_df <- data.frame(Died.At, Writer.At, First.Name, Second.Name, Sex)
```

i want to add a new column called id according to the name, so john and walt in this case, i know i can easily do this by

```
id<-c("1","1","2","2")
```

but i have a large data set to deal with , also, the name will not  appear again afterwards, so there will not be anymore john after walt, can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(writers_df)[, id:= .GRP, First.Name]
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
writers_df$id <- cumsum(!duplicated(writers_df$First.Name))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
writers_df %>%
     mutate(id = group_indices_(., .dots="First.Name"))
```

Comment: ah, that works! Thank you!